# Binding in XAML primitives

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am developing UWP app, and was trying to bind some property to primitive in XAML, and dont find how can I do it.
I have a C# class with static values:

```
 public class DevicePreferences
 {
     public static double InputTextFontSize = App.IsMobileDevice ? 22 : 18;
     public static double TitleTextBoxSize = App.IsMobileDevice ? 20 : 16;
     public static double ImageButtonSize = App.IsMobileDevice ? 40: 35;
 }
```

and I was looking something like this:

```
<x:Double x:Key="MyCustomValue">{local:DevicePreferences.TitleTextBoxSize}</x:Double>
```

I am wondering, is there any way to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `DataContext` of whatever control you want to bind to the `TitleTextBoxSize` property, you can bind to it directly as suggested here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e0e426ba-4feb-4571-b80b-7ba8818079b6/uwpstatic-property-binding?forum=wpdevelop

But you can't do something like this:

```
<x:Double x:Key="MyCustomValue">{local:DevicePreferences.TitleTextBoxSize}</x:Double>
```

You can only put constant `double` values inside the `<x:Double>` element.

Comment: Thank for reply, I have searched for couple days and find nothing about it. Looks like you right, there is no way to handle it.